# what is cookie length and how can I find what cookie length my site use?

Tags: cookies

Pay Per Click company asked me what cookie length do we use for our website, but have no idea what this means. I then google it and found to look under google Chrome > Developer tool > Resource > Cookies but there was many other cookies for our site, which one to consider?

PHPSESSID
__unam
__utma
__utmb
__utmc
__utmz
__stid
__uset

Answer (score 1):

A site never has a fixed cookie length. Every single cookie can have a different time and date on which it expires. I'm not sure which one you should consider. That depends on which cookies you are interested in. For example, if you want to know how much longer the PHP session will exist, look what the cookie expire date of PHPSESSID is.